# Word, Paragraphs.Add does not return the paragraph that has just been added

Tags: vba, ms-word

Consider this word document:

[image: A word document with only one paragraph and some text inside it]

Now, the following code should insert a new paragraph, and make it the selected one.

```
Sub Macro1()    
    Dim p As Paragraph       
    Set p = ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add()
    p.Range.Select    
End Sub
```

Instead this is the result. A new paragraph has actually been added but then it selects the previous one.
That's a bit puzzling because no matter where you add the new paragraph, it should be that that is selected at the end and not the previous one.

[image]

Comment: Seems logical to me. A paragraph is a piece of text between paragraph symbols. You are adding a new paragraph symbol, so its paragraph is what comes before that new paragraph symbol. You are adding the new symbol before the old symbol, so the old symbol is pushed out and is not a part of the new paragraph.

Comment: I thought a paragraph was the text to the paragraph sign, not the only paragraph sign. If what you say is true, it means that it 'breaks' the existing paragraph by adding a paragraph between the existing text and its paragraph sign :-(

Comment: You do have the caret before the exiting paragraph symbol. `p.Next.Range.Select`?

Comment: @Gserg, it's not relative to the current selection, but to the document structure, so where is the caret should not be relevant

Comment: A paragraph is indeed the text to the paragraph sign, including the paragraph sign. Yes, it breaks the existing (last) paragraph, because it cannot place the insertion point after the last paragraph in the document (`Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` will bring you to before the last paragraph sign, but for any other paragraph it will collapse to after the respective paragraph sign). Yes, it is inconsistent and annoying.

Comment: @Gserg, if you write it as an answer, providing also a way to actually select the just-added paragraph (maybe more than one) i'm going to accept it as an answer

Comment: Of course.  You could always read the MS help page on Paragraphs.add which explain perfecty the result you are seeing.

Comment: @freeflow I don't see it explained on the [help page for Paragraphs.add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphs.add). Not only that, but this specific example is given at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphs.add#example, and is wrongly described as "*adds a new paragraph mark at the end of the active document*", when in fact it adds a new paragraph mark one character before the end of the active document.

Comment: @Gserg then what does "The range before which you want the new paragraph to be added. The new paragraph doesn't replace the range." mean?

Comment: @freeflow The OP is not using this argument. Nor would it be useful, as it controls the place before which the paragraph mark is inserted, not the place after which it is inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paragraph is a series of characters up to and including a paragraph sign.

In order to insert a paragraph after an existing paragraph, you need to position your insertion point after the existing paragraph sign.
This can be done for any paragraph except the last one. For the last paragraph, you can only go as far as immediately before its insertion point:

```vb
Dim r As Range

' Suppose there are 10 paragraphs
Set r = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(3).Range
r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
r.Select ' Places the caret after the 3rd paragraph sign

Set r = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range
r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
r.Select ' Places the caret before the last paragraph sign
```

It is inconsistent and annoying, but that's what you get.

So when adding a paragraph to the very end, the insertion point is going to be before the existing paragraph sign, and thus the new paragraph sign is going to claim the old paragraph's body, becoming second-to-last.

So what you want is simply `Set p = ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Last` after the insertion.