Win32com Word: Paragraphs Overwriting Each Other
I am trying to use win32com to generate this document:

Here is my code:
import win32com.client

word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word_app.Visible = True
doc = word_app.Documents.Add()

para1 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add()
para1.Range.Text = "QTD"
para1.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault()

para2 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add()
para2.Range.Text = "Our top 3 performers are"
para2.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault()
para2.Range.ListFormat.ListIndent()

para3 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add()
para3.Range.Text = "X"
para3.Range.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault()
para3.Range.ListFormat.ListIndent()

para4 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add()
para4.Range.Text = "Y"
para4.Range.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault()
para4.Range.ListFormat.ListIndent()

para5 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add()
para5.Range.Text = "Z"
para5.Range.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault()
para5.Range.ListFormat.ListIndent()

para6 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add()
para6.Range.Text = "YTD"
para6.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault()

doc.SaveAs(r"C:\test.docx")


However, when I run the code, all I am seeing in the document is

I believe the paragraphs are overwriting each other - does anyone know why this is going on?

What happens if you comment out the YTD lines, do you get a Z line?

Yes I do, also it should be indented one level to the right but it is instead indented multiple levels to the right.

You might consider removing some of the ListIndent() lines. I have never used win32com but it's possible these are adding indent upon indent. When you load the document into Word, highlight the line you see and choose Paragraph, what is the line spacing?

It's Multiple at 1.16. I'll try and remove some of the ListIndent() lines

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151954/word-paragraphs-add-does-not-return-the-paragraph-that-has-just-been-added

After a while, I found the correct answer is
para1.InsertParagraphAfter()

which returns a reference to the new, empty paragraph
If you don't want to leave any trailing bullet points, at the end of the last paragraph,
para7 = para6.InsertParagraphAfter()
para7.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers()

